# Button doesn't work in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have given link to button like this..It works fine on mozilla & chrome 
But It does not work on ie9,ie8 & ie7 .......

```
 <a href="view_package_details.php?holiday_id=<?php echo $row['holiday_id']; ?>">  <input name="" type="button" class="view-details-btn-input" /> </a>
```

I have put button like this..It works fine on mozilla & chrome & ie9
But It does not work on ie8 & ie7 .......

Can anyone suggect me regarding this....

thanks

Comment: You got a button inside a link. Thats completly weird. A link and a form submission fo different things. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why not just style the anchor tag? What purpose does the button actually serve?

Comment: i want to pass holiday_id to another page,so that i have given link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use input type and href then try this.

```
 <input name="" type="button" class="view-details-btn-input" onclick="window.location='view_package_details.php?holiday_id=<?php echo $row['holiday_id']; ?>'" />
```

Answer (score 3):

why are you doing that?

you can do something like this

```
<button onclick="window.location=view_package_details.php?holiday_id=<?php echo $row['holiday_id']; ?>;"/>
```

otherwise @Gareth Cornish is right, why not apply css to `a` tag to make it look like a button?

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to use button inside hyperlink.
user javascript window.location on onclick eventof button